# How to disable JTable mouse click?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and after click any row a JDialog open.I want to do until a JDialog not close then another JDialog will not open or disable mouse click on the rows.
Implemented source code are following:

```
table = new JTable();
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {                 
Update update=new Update();     
try{                    
 int row=table.getSelectedRow();
 String getvalue= (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
 update.setVisible(true);
 //here I want to disable mouseclick listener
 table.setEnabled(false);   //It does not work
   }
 });
```

Note: I want to update my data using JDialog.

Need to help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no class in the standard API called `jdialogbox` nor even `jdialog` though there is one that is called `JDialog`.  If you mean one of those, then make it modal & the problem should be solved.  BTW - Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: yes i mean JDialog @ Andrew Thompson sir

Comment: How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:D The JDialog has a property named **modal**. Set it to: true. Something like this

> jDialog1.setModal(true);

You should also set the **alwaysOnTop** property to true as well

That should do it.